# How can I configure PuTTY to ignore right-click events?

Tags: unix, putty

I'm trying to configure portable PuTTY to access an Accu COBOL application.

The problem is that the right mouse button click causes an unexpected character entry in the  application for careless (read "not power user") users.

Accu COBOL uses `/etc/a_termcap` to control terminal properties. The version running on our system did not have an xterm entry. I found a model xterm with mouse control in an Accu COBOL 85 user's manual PDF and added it to `/etc/a_termcap`.

Unfortunately, it is not commented and I can't identify the mouse related settings. I need a configuration setting to tell PuTTY to ignore a right click unless the shift key is held down. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Under *Configuration → Window → Selection → Action of mouse buttons*, choose the "Windows" mode, then save this to the default session.